# pyflink AttributeError: type object 'EnvironmentSettings' has no attribute 'in_streaming_mode'

Tags: python, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis, pyflink

```py
%pyflink
from pyflink.table import EnvironmentSettings, StreamTableEnvironment

env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.in_streaming_mode()
table_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(environment_settings=env_settings)
```

Will fail with the following context:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-cfd5e4663f51> in <module>
      1 from pyflink.table import EnvironmentSettings, StreamTableEnvironment
      2 
----> 3 env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.in_streaming_mode()
      4 table_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(environment_settings=env_settings)

AttributeError: type object 'EnvironmentSettings' has no attribute 'in_streaming_mode'
```

I am running a Zeppelin notebook in AWS Kinesis Data analytics and all of the documentation suggests that this is the correct way to initial the environment.

This was pulled directly from their getting started repository amazon-kinesis-data-analytics-java-examples `python\GettingStarted\getting-started.py`

According to flink [docs](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.16/flink-python/pyflink/examples/table/word_count.py) examples

```
t_env = TableEnvironment.create(EnvironmentSettings.in_streaming_mode())
```

is sufficient but alas it fails for the same reason.

And showcased in the API docs themselves [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/python/table/intro_to_table_api/)

I cannot find an example where `in_streaming_mode()` is not called but it isn't an attribute on the EnvironmentSettings.

What am I doing wrong? Where is some worthwhile documentation on this stuff?

Comment: I'm having the same issue - very frustrating that examples in Flink's own documentation don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Zepppelin comes with built-in envs already initialized. Use either:

```
%flink.ipyflink

print(bt_env, st_env)
```

```
<pyflink.table.table_environment.BatchTableEnvironment object at 0x7fbc0fb2c970> 
<pyflink.table.table_environment.StreamTableEnvironment object at 0x7fbc0f6c6c10>
```